# I got verbal offer few weeks back

Tags: communication, job-search, job-offer

I got verbal offer few weeks back, but he is neither responding to emails nor phone calls, have tried mailing interviewing managers as well but no response.

---

I had already called them several times, and also told them to update me if it is given to someone else. But still no reply.

Comment: I presume that tour question is "what should I do??".

Comment: I had already called them several times, and also told them to update me if it is given to someone else. But still no reply.

Answer (score 9):

Understand this: **A verbal offer is the same as no offer.**

- Until the offer is extended to you in writing (e-mail, printed copy etc.), assume there is no offer.
- Until the offer is accepted by you and the acceptance is acknowledged by the organization (i.e., acknowledgement of receipt), there is no confirmation on your acceptance of the offer.

You must follow up (as you already did), and if you have their contact number, give them a call and emphasize that you need a formal copy of the offer with the terms and conditions of the employment (which is pretty standard process).

If you see there is substantial delay, I'd advise to keep looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending an email saying saying somethign along the lines of "I really liked your job offer, company culture and the project. I would like to start, or at least have a start date, as I have recently had a very positive interview and am expecting to receive an offer any day now".

That puts him under pressure to contact you. Of course, it could back fire, but how would you then be worse off than you are now?